# Getting NaN Javascript

Tags: javascript

have my json response as

```
{"data":[
{
"percentage":94.3,
"population":53193
}]
}
```

I'm trying to insert the data to span is

My Javascript

```
$.post("<?php echo $baseUrl . '/population'; ?>", function(data) {
                $('.percentage').text(parseFloat(data.percentage));
                $('.population').text(parseInt(data.population));
            }, 'JSON');
```

Im getting NaN
How do i resolve this

Comment: `data` doesn't have a `percentage` or `population` property. It's an **array** that has a single element in it, which is the object with those properties.

Comment: Please only use relevant tags. This question has nothing to do with [tag:php].